# box.net file actions - displaying a link in the box console

Tags: box-api

edit :

it seems the question wasn't very clear. i am trying to get a link to show up inside the yellow bar at the top of the page, so that i could redirect the user to my website at the end of the file action.

the yellow bar appears after the user initiates a file action and contacts my service on the final callback url. since the yellow bar shows whatever i return from my final callback url, i tried sending an a href tag. but this doesn't seem to work. the box server escapes the html and i see

```
<a href /a>
```

as plain text in the yellow bar.

Comment: Is there an example of an application or partner of Box's that does this already?  It isn't really clear where you're trying to get your link to show up.  File-actions already let you get something into Box's UI for users of your application

Comment: the link needs to show up inside the yellow update bar at the top so that i can link to relevant information on my website.